# Неправильно работает регистрация нового пользователя

Tags: python, django

После регистрации пользователя перекидывает на `login.html` с ошибкой `error: True`. При этом пользователь сохраняется в базе, но не может потом авторизоваться. Пишет, что неправильный логин или пароль.

views.py

```
def regpage(request):
username = request.POST.get('username')
password = request.POST.get('password')
if request.method == 'POST':
    uf = UserForm(request.POST)
    # upf = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
    if uf.is_valid() and request.POST.get('password') == request.POST.get('password1'):
        uf.save()
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'username': username, 'errors': True})

    context = {'UserForm': uf,
               'erUF': uf.errors, }
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)

context = {'uf': UserForm()}
return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Подтвердите пароль', 'class': 'form-control'}))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')
    widgets = {
        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'example@email.com', 'class': 'form-control'}),
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Имя', 'class': 'form-control'}),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Фамилия', 'class': 'form-control'}),
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Логин', 'class': 'form-control'}),
        # 'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Пароль'}),
        # Почему не показываются плэйсхолдеры на пароль, а в логине показываются?
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Пароль', 'class': 'form-control'}),
    }
```

Comment: Активировать пользователя небось забыли

Comment: Нет, пароль сохранялся в незашифрованном виде. Помогла замен forms.ModelForm на UserCreationForm